# How call another class on android?

Tags: android, android-intent

it is very basically .. sorry.

I want in MainActivity

after onCreate , call AutoUpdate.class.

AutoUpdate.class is extends Activity.

MainActivity

```
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Call AutoUpdate.class
 }
```

How call another class on android? 
Perhaps, can I use

```
Intent intent=  new Intent(this,AutoUpdate.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

?

Comment: Your own suggestion is correct. More info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). The official Android Developer site offers a lot of documentation and some valid examples, so try to use it as your primary resource: you'll find answers to basic questions like this a lot faster there than asking on StackOverflow and waiting for a response :)

Comment: It's OK to use Intent which your suggestion. or using intent code by one code,  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AutoUpdate.class);  [More info about startActivity(Intent) methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent))

Comment: Why? in OnCreate MainActivity call to AutoUpdate.class. When run , your app always call to AutoUpdate.class.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this tutorial [How to switch between Activities in Android](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/) which explain more details about Activities

lets take a look

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

this will navigate you to SecondActivity

and if you want to sent extra data you can use this before startActivity

```
i.putExtra("key", "value");
```

and to get it in the SecondActivity, you can use

```
String myDataFromFirstActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");// will returns "value"
```

there are a lots of  things to learn "happy learning"